# use for statement to extract bytes from iptables

Tags: for-loop, iptables

I am trying to pipe the output of no of bytes allowed(ACCEPT) by INPUT chain and then add them. However, I want to use the for statement to get the no of bytes.

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -x
```

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
4      583 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
0       0 ACCEPT     all  --  tap0   any     anywhere             anywhere
554091 331350353 ACCEPT     all  --  any     anyanywhere   anywhere

520    49008 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere        anywhere

2576   279561 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Now using for statement, I want to extract the bytes only for target ACCEPT.

Something like:

```
for bytes in target
```

I am not sure how to use the for statement in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the for statement in this case. Just make a command pipeline. Print iptables, do grep, get the bytes column using cut command and then do paste and then add all bytes using bc command. All in one pipeline as required in your homework.

Comment: Thank you..@sysadmin... I have already done it the way you have mentioned here...Wanted to use minimal pipes. :)